# Kivy GUI breaks after opening a Mayavi window

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I have a Kivy GUI which is supposed to open a Mayavi 3D plot window after pressing the respective button. The plot works just fine but after closing the Mayavi window, the main GUI remains unresponsive with the plotting button stuck. Ironically, the stuck-down button is the only element which responds to anything by producing the same plot again. Other GUI elements do not respond to anything, and furthermore, the GUI elements no longer scale when the window is resized.

The problem can be reproduced with this minimal Python script:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from mayavi import mlab

class MyApp(App):

    def show(self, _=None):
        mlab.test_contour3d()
        mlab.show()

    def build(self):
        btn1 = Button(text='Oh hai', size_hint=(0.5, 0.5))
        btn1.bind(on_release=self.show)
        return btn1


MyApp().run()
```

And it gets stuck all the same. I also tried to produce the plot using Vispy but the failure mechanism was no different. Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: That's interesting, and I was able to reproduce it with this example. I think the problem may be that mayavi's use of opengl messes up the Kivy opengl context, but if that's the case I don't know how to fix it. It would also mean that Kivy's internals are continuing to work fine, just the gui is corrupted, which is why the button still works.

Comment: Never worked with kivy, but don't you need in general to tell the parent process (kivy here) that the child process (here mayavi) has ended? Maybe some ideas in this code (https://youtu.be/1d3eRCdyNHQ?t=177) or on this doc (https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.window.html).